# Properties of first-order stochastic dominance for conditional CDFs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Suppose the random variable $X$ is distributed over the real line. There are two cumulative distribution functions (CDFs) $F_X$ and $G_X$. The expected values of $X$ exist and are finite under both $F_X$ and $G_X$. Furthermore, suppose $F_X$ first-order stochastically dominates (FOSD) $G_X$, that is, $F_X(x) \leq G_X(x)  \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $F_X(x_0) < G_X(x_0)  $ for at least one $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose there is another random varibable $Y$. $Y$ and $X$ are dependent random variables - not merely deterministic functions of each other. Thus, $F_{X,Y}$ and $F_{X|Y}$ represent the joint and conditional CDFs following the marginal $F_X$, respectively. The same applies to the joint and conditional CDFs following the marginal $G_X$: $G_{X,Y}$ and $G_{X|Y}$. Again, all expected values (joint, marignal, and conditional) exist and are finite.

Suppose that the distributions conditional on $X$ are identical, that is, $F_{Y|X}(y|x)=G_{Y|X}(y|x)  \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Can we conclude from FOSD of $F_X$ over $G_X$ and the previous sentence that $F_{X|Y}$ FOSD $G_{X|Y}$?

Comment: If $Y=X$, then $F_{X|Y}=G_{X|Y}$ and so the property $F_{X|Y}(x_0|y)<G_{X|Y}(x_0|y)$ for at least one $x_0$ is lost, I would expect the other property to hold however.

Comment: Thanks. I should specify that $X \neq Y$.

Comment: Not really, it would also work if $Y$ is any deterministic one to one function of $X$.

Comment: @P.Quinton: Thanks, I will add that $Y$ is a "proper" random variable and not merely a function of $X$.